# Traversing exactly n edges, from source node to destination node, find longest path

Tags: algorithm, graph

Suppose we have a **weighted** graph, it is **directed** and **cyclic**. Every node has an edge directed toward every other node. There are no edges that connect a node to itself.

Now we have a source node, and a destination node. I have to start at the source node and traverse exactly **n edges** and end up at the destination node. Where **n** is some arbitrary positive integer (possibly greater than the number of nodes in the graph).

When we traverse an edge, we add it to our **sum** (edge weights are all **positive**). Now the path we take to reach our destination node can have cycles. How can we maximise our **sum**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not allowed cycles the problem is NP-complete - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Assuming that you are allowed paths that can include cycles e.g. A,B,C,B,C

For i = 1..N compute, for each node, the length of the longest path of length i that terminates at that node. Save the length and the identity of the node just before the N.

Case i=0 is just a path of length 0 with previous node null for every node.

Work out case i+1 from case i by considering, for each node, every edge terminating in that node.

At the end chose the node for step N with the longest path terminating at it and use the records of previous nodes to trace back.

(The above was actually intended to compute the longest path between any two nodes because I misread the question, but you can modify it in the beginning to extend only paths which start at the source node, and in the end to consider only paths that end at the destination node).

Example added after question ab=1,ac=2,bd=10,cd=1 find the longest 2-step path from A to D.

i=0 start with A

i=1 longest path to B is length 1, last visited A. Longest to C is length 2, last visited A

i=2 longest to A is length 4 last visited C. Longest to D is 11 last visited B (max of 1+10 from B and 2+1 from C).

We wanted length 2 so we stop here and take the answer computed for D.

Comment: It isn't clear why your algorithm should work. The longest path of size N is not necessarily composed of the longest path of size N-1 and another edge.

Comment: What if N is much larger than |V|? Like |V| is around 20 and N can be as great as 10^9.

Comment: @n.m. The longest path of length n terminating at node X is necessarily composed of a longest path of length n-1 terminating at some node Y which is a neighbor of X and then the edge from Y to X. If it did not contain a longest path of length n-1 to Y it could be increased by modifying it to do so. This algorithm computes longest paths to ALL nodes, not just the final destination.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 I needed in any case to modify it to consider and extend only paths which start at the source node. At stage i, consider only nodes for which there exists a path of length i from the source node to that node. For these nodes keep a note of the length of the longest path of length i from the source node to that node, and the second last node on that path. Using a map this takes up only space linear in the number of such nodes. However note that if the graph is well connected the set of reachable nodes will become the set of all nodes very quickly.

Comment: "The longest path of length n terminating at node X is necessarily composed of a longest path of length n-1 terminating at some node Y which is a neighbor of X and then the edge from Y to X" How so? ab=1,ac=2,bd=10,cd=1.

Comment: @n.m. I have worked through that example and find no surprises - as n increases the longest paths all include BDBDB... sections using the long BD link. Did you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: The task is to find the longest path of size 2 from a to d.

Comment: Wait I think I understand it now, you want to find the longest path to b and the longest path to c separately.